# How do I handle a site with subdomain using the Domain Access module?

Tags: 8, multi-sites, domain-access

I have a site which as a federal level and a subdomain by state. I'm using Domain Access module which works great for some basic things such as contents by domains. But I've got other challenge to solve and I didn't find any solution for it.
I would like :

1. The states to be able to have their own menu. I tried the Domain Menu Access module but it didn't fit my needs since it does not enable each state to fill his own entries of the menu.
   For example the federal menu could be : Presentation, Federal item 1, Federal Item 2 whereas state menu would be Presentation (same page as Federal menu), State item 1, State item 2.
2. The states to be able to enrich some kind of content written by the federal site. Let's say I've got a content type name Presentation Page. I would like, for a given Presentation Page content, each state to be able to add a text field to complete the content of the base material.
3. The domain access checkboxes to be prefilled with the current domain AND the main domain on some content types. Some content should be presented on the federal site but filled by states and I would be great to avoid having to check the main site checkbox for each content created.

I didn't find any modules or any way to achieve those goals. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Can you give a little more detail, with examples, for some of the items. Like for the menu, what does  "enable each state to fill his own entries" mean: what would be in a menu edit page, and how would the menus look to a visitor on the Federal site vs State sites? For item two, what would the edit page look like if a state was "able to add a text field to complete the content of the base material", and how would it look like to a visitor on different sites? Can you also give URLs for content that is on the Federal site and the same URLs for that content on State sites?

Comment: I don't know how it would look like on the admin menu. For item one, I would like the entries to be customizable for each state. For item two, the visitor would see, on the state page the same content as on the federal page but with a bloc of text giving some extra information relative to the state.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't, or don't want to, use the Domain Menu Access module to create a menu item called "Federal item 1" that only appears on the Federal domain, and create a second menu item called "State item 1" that only appears on the State domain? For the content fields that should only appear on State domains: Does the version of the Domain Access module you are using add css classes with the domain name to the `<body>` tag? If so, how about using css styles to show/hide State-only fields?

Comment: About the Domain Menu Access I cannot figured out how to use it properly. It just allow me to access a settings page which is not specific to any domain. Right now I'm using a menu for each state and the menu block presence depend on the domain. About the content field that should be visible on the state page my problematic is that I want each state to be able to add information, so it cannot be a simple field. I thought about using comments but I looked like an ugly trick.

Comment: Is the problem with the Domain Menu Access module that you don't see the "Manage menu visibility per domain" fieldset when editing a menu item? Or is the problem that you need it so that when on the Menu admin page you would have something like "Item 1", but on the front-end that menu item's name would appear as "Item 1" for Federal, "Lorem ipsum" for State Foo, "Dolor sit amat" for State Bar, etc. For nodes, is it that you need a field whose content changes for each domain: the content for "Baz Field" would be blank for Federal, "Consectetur" for State Foo, "Adipiscing" for State Bar, etc?

Comment: I don't see the "Manage menu visibility per domain" fieldset when editing a menu item indeed and for nodes that's exactly what I would like to have.

Comment: You should create a support [issue for Domain Menu Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/domain_menu_access?categories=All). For the content fields, I'm wondering if [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) would work. It will depend on whether the Conditional Fields module has access to each Domain's enabled status for a node. If so, you would create a field for each domain, and make whether a field is visible dependent on whether a domain is enabled for the node.

Comment: I tried conditionnal fields but unfortunately it doesn't enable condition based on domain. I thought about creating two content types. One for the Federation and one for the states, the state content referencing a Federation content. But the problem with that solution is that I would like all the state content "extending" from the same federation content to have the same url.

Comment: This may be a little convoluted, but... How about adding a text field (hidden or visible) that contains the names of every domain that is selected for a node, and use that for the "dependee" field with Conditional Fields (you may need to use a RegEx value for the condition). Some custom JavaScript could be used to update the text field whenever a domain is selected/deselected. That way you have Conditional Fields doing all the heavy lifting, and the only custom code you have to maintain is a little JavaScript.